# tools to create dfa from grammar rules

Tags: rule, dfa

I am looking for any tool or software that converts a set of rules into a Deterministic Finite Automata. Actually I'm developing a stemmer, something like porter stemmer for Enlglish. I have a set of rules that remove suffixes and/or prefixes from terms leaving a stem. I can translate this rules into a DFA manually, but it's an adhoc solution and results into flexibility problems.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about converting rules to a DFA, but for manipulation of DFA's, as well as testing and debugging  them a great (free) program is [JFlap](http://www.jflap.org). It has a ton of built-in tools, as well as support for a variety of automatons and machines. Maybe somewhere in there is what you're looking for!